# CSS Z-Index stacking context puzzle

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have the following markup:
http://jsfiddle.net/dy4TG/3/

```
<div class="slide-wrap">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="text">Text here</div>
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

the `.slide` div must be absolutely positioned, and `.slide-wrap` would have position: relative.

Is it possible for the `.overlay` div to be between the image and the `.text` div? I need the stacking context to be like this (highest to lowest):

-Text

-Overlay

-Image

Thanks!

Live example here: http://movable.pagodabox.com (inspect the slideshow... in the specific context of this example, "overlay" has the class "kineticjs-content", and the `.slide` div is inside of the `#slides` parent div.

Comment: "Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net " - I'd upvote *that* question. `:)` Nice choice in pagodabox, I like their setup.

Comment: You just sent a link to the jsfiddle.net homepage, not an actual fiddle!

Comment: Umm... Duh! Where's **your** http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: ok ok one sec i didn't get your irony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to make sure everything is positioned absolutely, this way you can float everything however you wish, with any z-index.

css:

```
.overlay {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 50;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50px;
}
img{
    z-index: 20;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 5px;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000;
}
.text {
    z-index: 999;
    color: #888;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 5px;
}
.slide-wrap{
    position:relative;   
}
.slide{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100px;
}​
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/a7Apz/3

Comment: this is great Mash... but I realized my question wasn't specific enough... take another look if you get a chance plz! Thank you!

Comment: @j-man86 http://jsfiddle.net/a7Apz/2/ seems to still work fine, just added the new HTML, made .slide-wrap position: relative, and .slide position:absolute.  Did I miss something in  the question?

Comment: That new fiddle does it... update your answer when you get a chance. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You **must** give a `z-index` to `.text`, and it has to be the highest one if you want it to be on top of everything. And you **must not** give a `z-index` to `.slide` or `.slide-wrap`, as that would create a new stacking context, with the text and image nested in it. You need the text, the image and the overlay on the same [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context).

Here is a jsfiddle to [demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/g2aV5/). And here is the [same idea applied to your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dy4TG/1/).

Comment: sorry... I changed the question a little bit

Comment: The same principle still applies. As I said, you must give a z-index to .text, and you must not give a z-index to .slide - http://jsfiddle.net/dy4TG/4/.